# Is there a closed form for the infinite product $\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigl(1+{x \over 2^n} \bigr)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

It has been a long time ago since I first encountered the following infinite product :
$$
\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigl(1+{x \over 2^n} \bigr) = (1 + x) \bigl(1 + {x \over 2}\bigr)\bigl(1 + {x \over 4}\bigr)\bigl(1 + {x \over 8}\bigr)  \cdots 
$$
to my knowledge I haven't seen a closed form, but I would appreciate if gathering some information about this product. Does it relate to any known functions?

Comment: Have a look at [Pochhammer symbols etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol)where $a = -x,q = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: The q-Pochhammer symbol : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html  (15 seconds too late )

Comment: ...which has nice asymptotics

Comment: @JJacquelin I have been on the other end w.r.t you (by far greater units of time usually) on many more occasions  - on the DE tag ;).

Comment: Thank you guys for your useful links as well your fast response. I appreciate it.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\log\left(1+\frac{x}{2^n}\right) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}\left(\frac{x^m}{2^{nm}}\right)=\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m\left(1-2^{-m}\right)}x^m$$
hence the product can be written as $\exp\left(\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m\left(1-2^{-m}\right)}x^m\right)$, but that is far from being nice.

Comment: Thank you Jack for sharing your view of this product.

Answer (score 2):

If we have a function $f$ that satisfies these conditions: $f(0)=1, f(-a_n)=0, n\in [0,\infty)$, so we have that the function f is equal to an infinite product: $$f(x)=\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1+\frac{x}{a_n})$$ But, we can expand this infinite product as a **infinite sum**, as follows: $$f(x)=1+x\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n}+x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n a_k}+x^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \sum_{m=k+1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n a_k a_m}+...$$ This result you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739041/can-we-expand-a-infinite-product). So, if $a_n=2^n$, then $$f(x)=\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1+\frac{x}{a_n})=1+x\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n}+x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty 2^{-(n+k)}+...=1+2x+\frac{4}{3}x^2+...$$
Let $b_{n,m}(x)=\sum_{k=m}^\infty \frac{b_{n-1,k}(1)x^k}{2^k}, b_{1,m}(x)=\sum_{k=m}^\infty (\frac{x}{2})^k$. Then, $f(x)=b_{0,0}(1)+xb_{1,0}(1)+x^2b_{2,0}(1)+...$. We have that: $$b_{1,m}(x)=\frac{2x^m}{2^m(2-x)}$$ $$b_{2,m}(x)=\frac{8x^m}{4^m(4-x)}$$ $$b_{3,m}(x)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{64x^m}{8^m(8-x)}$$
My conjecture is that: $$b_{n,m}(x)=c_n\frac{2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}x^m}{2^{\frac{nm(n+1)}{2}}(2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}-x)}$$ $$b_{n,0}(1)=\frac{2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}c_n}{2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}-1}$$
But I don't tested for now this result.

**UPDATE:** It is easy to proof by induction that $$b_{n,m}(1)=\frac{1}{2^{nm+n(n+1)/2}}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^k}}$$
So, from this we have that $$\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1+\frac{x}{2^n})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_{n,0}(1)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^k}}$$

A little error here: in fact, $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n2^{-n(n-1)/2}\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^k}}$$

**EXPLANATION**: $f(x)=(1+x)\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+\frac{x}{2^n})=(1+x)\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1+\frac{x/2}{2^n})=(1+x)f(x/2)$. Let $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n$. So $$\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n = (1+x)\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n (\frac{x}{2})^n = a_0+\sum_{n\geq 1} \left[ \frac{a_n}{2^n}+\frac{a_{n-1}}{2^{n-1}}\right]x^n \Rightarrow \sum_{n\geq 1} \left[ a_n(1-\frac{1}{2^n})+\frac{a_{n-1}}{2^{n-1}}\right] x^n =0, \forall x \in D(f)$$
So $$a_n=\frac{2a_{n-1}}{2^n-1}=2^ka_{n-k}\prod_{m=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{2^{n-m} -1}= 2^na_0\prod_{m=1}^n\frac{1}{2^m-1}, k=n$$
Since $\prod_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{2^m-1}=\prod_{m=1}^n\frac{2^{-m}}{1-2^{-m}}=2^{-\sum_{m=0}^n m}\prod_{m=1}^m\frac{1}{1-2^{-m}}=2^{-n(n+1)/2}\prod_{m=1}^m\frac{1}{1-2^{-m}}$, so $$a_n=2^{-n(n-1)/2}\prod_{m=1}^m\frac{1}{1-2^{-m}}$$ Then we are done. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Dear Tio, I am not in position to test your results but I know (from when working with it a long time ago) that every single result requires a lot of hard work.

Comment: Warning: I reached to a REAL result here. I edited my answer. Please view my approach.