# Limit of $p_n = f(a, n) + (1- f(a, n))p_{n - 1}, p_0 = a, 0 < a < 0.5$

Tags: calculus, probability, limits, recurrence-relations

How does one compute the limit $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} p_n$ for the sequence $p_n = f(a, n)  + (1- f(a, n))p_{n - 1}$ with $p_0 = a$, where $0 < a < \dfrac{1}{2}$, $f(a,n)=\dfrac{a}{2^n}$?

Comment: If $u_n=\prod_{k=1}^n (1-\frac{a}{2^k})$, you can put for $n\geq 1$ $q_n=p_n/u_n$ (and $q_0=p_0$). This gives (if  i have not made a mistake) $q_n=q_{n-1}+a/(2^n u_n)$, a telescopic relation that gives $q_n$, and as $u_n$ has for limit $\prod_{k\geq 1} (1-\frac{a}{2^k})$, this gives you an expression (not simple...)  for the limit.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on your problem and at last found the same thing that **Kelenner** said in his comment, anyway I write it to be another comment.

$p_n = p_{n - 1} + (1 - p_{n - 1})\dfrac{a}{2^n}=\dfrac{a}{2^n}+(1-\dfrac{a}{2^n})p_{n-1}=\lambda_n+(1-\lambda_n)p_{n-1}$ where $\lambda_n=\dfrac{a}{2^n}>0$.

$p_n =\lambda_n+(1-\lambda_n)p_{n-1}$ shows $a=p_0< p_1< p_2< p_3<\cdots<1$ then it's converge. Also
$$\frac{1-p_n}{1-p_{n-1}}=1-\lambda_n$$
and
$$\frac{1-p_k}{1-a}=\prod\limits_{n=0}^k\frac{1-p_n}{1-p_{n-1}}=\prod\limits_{n=0}^k(1-\lambda_n)$$
Thus
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}p_k=1-(1-a)\prod\limits_{n=0}^\infty(1-\dfrac{a}{2^n})$$
right product has simplified by Jack D'Aurizio [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426749/is-there-a-closed-form-for-the-infinite-product-prod-n-0-infty-bigl1x?rq=1).