# Can we expand a infinite product?

Tags: summation, infinite-product

I was playing on with the infinite product of the sine: $$\sin(x)=x\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-\frac{x^2}{k^2\pi^2})$$

If we try expand this product, we will get the sum of reciprocals of squares of natural numbers and some others series: $$\sin(x)=x(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}+junk)$$

I thought a scheme:

| Term | 1st factor | 2nd factor | 3rd factor | ... | Nth factor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st term | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 |
| 2nd term | $-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}$ | $-\frac{x^2}{4\pi^2}$ | $-\frac{x^2}{9\pi^2}$ | ... | $-\frac{x^2}{N^2\pi^2}$ |

It's like this: first we do the product of all the columns of the first row. Then we need to get all the combinations which have ONE column of the second row, so we will have for the second term $-x^2\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^2\pi^2}$. The third term  will be the sum of all combinations, but with TWO columns of the second row, like this: $x^4\sum_{n=1, k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2k^2\pi^4}$, and so on. So, aplying the limit as $N\rightarrow\infty$, the final product is like:

$$x\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-\frac{x^2}{k^2\pi^2})=x-x^3\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2\pi^2}+x^5\sum_{n=1,k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2k^2\pi^4}-...$$

But, I want to generalize a product like $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{x}{a_n})$, but I don't know how to manipulate the sum $\sum_{n_1 = 1, n_k = n_{k-1}+1, k = 2,3,...,m}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{n_k}$. So, if someone can help me, I'll be grateful.

### AN APPROACH:

If we have a function $f$ defined by this way:
$$f(x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{x}{a_n})$$ We have that the series of f at 0 equal this expression:
$$f(x)=1-x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n}+x^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n a_k} -x^3\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \sum_{m=k+1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n a_k a_m} +...$$
If we develop these functions, we can solve for all functions of the type above:

$$b_k(n)=\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{b_{k-1}(m)}{a_m}, b_1(n)=\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{a_m}$$

For $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2\pi^2}$, we have that $f(x^2)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$, and $b_k(n)=\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{b_{k-1}(m)}{\pi^2 m^2}$

Comment: This is how Euler discovered the sum of the squares of the reciprocals.

Comment: Yes, I forgotten to mention Euler, thanks

Comment: The coefficient of $x^n$ in the series expansion of $\prod(1+\lambda_kx)$ will be the $n$th elementary symmetric "polynomial" in infinitely many "variables" $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots$. (Compare with Vieta's formulas.) The Newton-Girard formulas tell you how to write elementary symmetric polynomials in terms of power symmetric polynomials, which in the case of $\sin x$ means you can write the coefficients as polynomials in zeta values for example.

Comment: I know this might not be in the spirit of the question, but you may enjoy reading on Fourier Series, as I feel like it's much more natural approach to these particular Zeta functions.

Comment: Second remark, there's something special about the $(a_n)$ in the original sine, specifically they can be written as a constant times a multiplicative function, that is to say: $a_n = 1/\pi^2 \cdot \chi(n)$, where $\chi(nm) = \chi(n) \chi(m)$. This might be an important observation, as it usually simplifies sums quite a bit.